# How should I start with Android development? I am basically a PHP HTML JAVASCRIPT developer

Tags: android, javascript, html5, corona-sdk

I am a PHP developer wanting to learn Android game programming.

I tried java with ADT and android SDK, but I found Java confusing because of its complex Object-Oriented structure.

I've heard we can develop mobile games with PhoneGap or Appcelator using HTML5 and JS. I know both of those very well, so I'd ratehr not use Java.

What tool or language should I start my Android game development in?

Comment: Did you read the [FAQ]? "How to get started"-questions are off-topic because only you can really answer them.

Comment: this is a question related to this community. I havent broke any rule in how to get started. I just wanted opinion that which language/tool should I prefer as per my experience in javascript/html5/php .. dont know why you "BIG REPUTED" people just try to interfere everywhere. If you dont want to give answer .. than please let someone else do it.. its a kind request to all the "BIG REPUTED" persons. @Anko

Comment: Sorry if it seems harsh, but the [rules](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) exist for good reasons. This question definitely falls under ["What tech should I use"](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/695/are-what-should-i-use-to-do-x-questions-really-on-topic-and-good). There are links at the bottom of the rules page with ideas for where to ask subjective questions instead.

Comment: its okay bro.. but still I am new user in this site and I didnt know the rules, if this site user cant give me suggestion than where should I get my answer? @Anko

Comment: I have read the FAQ and I read that we can ask about...

game-specific programming issues (**engine architecture**, game-related APIs, networking, **tools**, etc)

Comment: Yup, but *not* about *which one of them you should learn or use*. Those links I posted earlier explain why.

Comment: Hi Nishant, many of the games there on app stores are developed using web languages (php, JS/jQuery/ HTML5,...) only. So, instead of wasting your time on "How to Start Android Development", try to develop games in your HTML5 and start searching for "How to port my HTML5 app/Game to Android/ iOS / windows Phone/ BlackBerry OS(Yes, they all support!)

Comment: @sai thanks for your suggestion, just can you tell me the best tool which is good for generating 2d games using html5 and js

Comment: I am not sure, but I just started using INTEL XDK(an awesome cross platform TOOL for mobile webapps) a week ago, and you need to try it (I just started learning HTML & Js) That's why right now I can't give you exact info. <I am in no way connected with INTEL and just an user, by the way>

Comment: Also check out corona sdk, and titanium sdk those should set you in the right path

Answer (score 1):

In my own case, I found it extremely valuable to develop [my game](http://tempest.stormwarestudios.com/) using (almost) pure JavaScript, using [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org) to facilitate some more mundane tasks (event publish/subscribe, browser sniffing, DOM manipulation) as well as adopt its [AMD design](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) methodology.

Apart from this, I've written my own sound, graphics, sprite and network-packet modules, and linked the game client to a [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) game-server ([actionHero](http://actionherojs.com/), to be specific). My own model is client/server, which differs from your mileage. I wanted to include that here to illustrate that HTML5 game development is entirely in the realm of "possible", if you're structured and using technologies available to you to make your development tasks simpler.

In terms of pure JavaScript, check out http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/19/design-your-own-mobile-game/ ... it seems to be most of what you're looking for. I don't have experience with PhoneGap other than to suggest to continue to look into it, as it seems to be the right direction to go for your intended platform.

The trade-off of going the HTML5/JS/PhoneGap (cross-platform capability at reduced performance) route over the Java/Android SDK (better performance, but limited to Android devices) route is fairly obvious, but is also worth mentioning here.

Comment: thanks so much for your response.. I appreciate it and will sure look forward to your suggestions... :)